# Can I omit search results from a dataset in r?

Tags: r

My first work in databases was in FileMaker Pro. One of the features I really liked was the ability to do a complex search, and then with one call, omit those results and return anything from the original dataset that wasn't returned in the search. Is there a way to do this in R without having to flip all the logic in a search?

Something like:

```
everything_except <- df %>%
  filter(x == "something complex") %>% 
  omit()
```

My initial thought was looking into using a join to keep non-matching values, but thought I would see if there's a different way.

Update with example:
I'm a little hesitant to add an example because I don't want to solve for just this problem but understand if there is an underlying method for multiple cases.

```
set.seed(123)
event_df <- tibble(time_sec = c(1:120)) %>% 
  sample_n(100) %>%
  mutate(period = sample(c(1,2,3),
                         size = 100,
                         replace = TRUE),
         event = sample(c("A","B"), 
                        size = 100, 
                        replace = TRUE, 
                        prob = c(0.1,0.9))) %>% 
  select(period, time_sec, event) %>% 
  arrange(period, time_sec)

filter_within_timeframe <- function (.data, condition, time, lead_time = 0, lag_time = 0){
  condition <- enquo(condition)
  time <- enquo(time)
  filtered <- .data %>% slice(., 1:max(which(!!condition))) %>% 
    group_by(., grp = lag(cumsum(!!condition), default = 0)) %>% 
    filter(., (last(!!time) - !!time) <= lead_time & (last(!!time) - 
                                                        !!time) >= lag_time)
  return(filtered)
}

# this returns 23 rows of data. I would like to return everything except this data
event_df %>% filter_within_timeframe(event == "A", time_sec, 10, 0)

# final output should be 77 rows starting with...
# ~period,  ~time_sec,  ~event,
# 1,3,"B",
# 1,4,"B",
# 1,5,"B",
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `everything_except <- df %>% filter(x != "something complex")`

Comment: Adding onto akrun's answer, you can throw parens around the something complex and add the not operator (`!`) before the parens - that may be easier than trying to reverse a bunch of == to !=, especially if 'something complex' includes a lot of `and` and `or` clauses. example: `iris %>% filter(!(Species == "setosa"))`

Comment: I updated with an example. I'm not sure if (!) could be implemented without changing the custom function... which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @seansteele can you add a small example for `df` with `dput` so that it can be tested and also the expected output

Comment: updated... should give a clear enough example to work with

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join()` is great for this